# Initialization of the kmeans2 in python

Tags: python, initialization, scipy, k-means

I am using `scipy.cluster.vq.kmeans2` which, by definition, initializes the K-means randomly (given the pre-defined initialization method - random, points).

Is there a way to make the initialization stable, i.e., for the same initial centroids to obtain the same clustering results, but without using `minit='matrix'`? I really don't know what the initial point are but I want them to be the same for all simulations runs (e.g. for reproducible outputs).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can seed the default numpy random number generator, for example:

```
from numpy import random
random.seed(123)
```

as shown in the last example [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.vq.kmeans.html) (which seems to be applicable to `kmeans2` as well).